# Jest gives getState as undefined even after configuring

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing in React Testing Library and Jest. I have used `redux-toolkit` to manage the state of my app.

I am getting the following error after I run my first test:

```
    FAIL  src/components/user/Contact.test.js (15.178 s)
  Contact
    × renders correctly (815 ms)

  ● Contact › renders correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

       6 | describe("Contact", () => {
       7 |   test("renders correctly", () => {
    >  8 |     render(<Provider store={store}><Contact /></Provider>); 
         |           ^
       9 |     const inputElem = screen.getByLabelText(/Name/)
      10 |     expect(inputElem).toBeInTheDocument();
      11 |   });
```

Below is my Contact.test.js:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import store from "../../app/store";

describe("Contact", () => {
  test("renders correctly", () => {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Contact />
      </Provider>
    );
    const inputElem = screen.getByLabelText(/Name/);
    expect(inputElem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Below is my store.js which I am also using for my React app:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from "../features/auth/authSlice";
import adminReducer from "../features/admin/adminSlice";
import userReducer from "../features/user/userSlice";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    admin: adminReducer,
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HOC wrapper from the [Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function)?

It would look something like this with your `store`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from 'path/to/your/store'

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store,
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }

  // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
}
```

and in your test

```
import { renderWithProviders } from 'path/to/your/renderWithProviders'

describe("Contact", () => {
  test("renders correctly", () => {
    renderWithProviders(<Contact />);
    const inputElem = screen.getByLabelText(/Name/);
    expect(inputElem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```